# Attempting to use Elasticsearch Bulk API when _id is equal to a specific field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I am attempting to bulk insert documents into an index. I need to have _id equal to a specific field that I am inserting. I'm using ES v6.6

```
POST productv9/_bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "productv9", "_id": "in_stock"}}
{ "description" : "test", "in_stock" : "2001"}

GET productv9/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_id": "2001"
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the bulk statement it runs without any error. However, when I run the search statement it is not getting any hits. Additionally, I have many additional documents that I would like to insert in the same manner.

Comment: you have documents in the file or something else as a source?

Comment: the only document is { "description" : "test", "in_stock" : "2001"} and in_stock is a field within _source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suggest to do is to create an [ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) that will set the `_id` of your document based on the value of the `in_stock` field.

First create the pipeline:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/set_id
{
  "description" : "Sets the id of the document based on a field value",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "set" : {
        "field": "_id",
        "value": "{{in_stock}}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you can reference the pipeline in your bulk call:

```
POST productv9/doc/_bulk?pipeline=set_id
{ "index" : {}}
{ "description" : "test", "in_stock" : "2001"}
```

By calling `GET productv9/_doc/2001` you will get your document.

Comment: How _bulk without type can work on ES 6.6? Shouldn't it be `POST productv9/_doc/_bulk` ?

Comment: Yeah, I tested on ES7... fixed now.

Comment: @Val could you check out this question when you have time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72001990/how-to-pass-a-list-of-values-to-an-elasticsearch-query-from-another-query