# How to pass a list of values to an elasticsearch query (from another query)

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a map where a user can select a county. What I would like for it to be able to do,  is return all the 'encounters' that 'members' have had for that county.

The only thing is, that 'county' is not a field of the index that I need to return the documents for ('county' is a field in the 'member' index, whereas I want to return the documents from the 'encounters' index) (they are linked by 'memberId').

Here is what I currently do, to get members in a county.

```
GET member/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "county": "Ashtabula"
    }
  }
}
```

But this returns a list of documents for members in that county. What I need it to return is a list of memberId's for those documents. ('memberId' is just one field in 'member')

How I query for members in the 'encounters'

```
GET encounteressentials/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "encounterVantageId": "123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000"
    }
  }
}
```

But instead of matching for a single ID, I want to pass the list of memberId's from the first query to the second.

What is the best way to achieve this? Thank you.

Please let me know if you need a trimmed-down version of the index mapping, but it is basically 'encounters' with field 'memberId' and other fields, then 'members' with 'memberId' and 'county'.

Comment: You can simply try the `terms` query instead of match, as `terms` allows you to pass an array of values: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html

Comment: Hi @Val I have another question that is related to spring data elasticsearch https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72380663/how-to-return-one-field-from-a-query-spring-data-elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

Try with this examples using terms:

```
GET encounteressentials/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "encounterVantageId": [
        1,
        2
      ]
    }
  }
}
```