# How to return one field from a query (Spring Data Elasticsearch)

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am writing a query; in Kibana it's easy

```
GET populationstreamassignment/_search
{
    "query": {
    "match": {
      "healthyChildrenIndicator": true
    }
  }, 
  "_source": "memberId"
}
```

What I want to do is get a list of all the memberId's for 'healthy children'. But I want to translate this to java syntax.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Query;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;

/**
 Spring Data Elasticsearch repository for the {@link PopulationStreamAssignment} entity.
 */
public interface PopulationStreamAssignmentSearchRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<PopulationStreamAssignment, Long> {

    @Query("{\"match\": {\"?0\": \"?1\"}}")
    List<UUID> getMemberIdsByPopulationStream(String popStream, Boolean criteria);

}
```

This query has a few problems. Here is where I have questions..

1. How can I specify "_source" so that I only return the memberId field?
2. memberId is a UUID, can I have it directly return memberId's as a List of Values?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a [pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/pull/2151) being worked on that will allow to add source includes and source excludes to repository methods that are annotated with the `@Query` annotation, so this will be available in the next version.

Besides that, it is possible to set the source filter values to any provided implementation of the `Query` interface (`StringQuery`, `CriteriaQuery`, `NativeSearchQuery`). You'd need to create a repository fragment (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) to add a function that builds and uses one of these queries if you wish to integrate it in a repository.

The entity you use to read the data would need to have a property that matches the returned values like

```java
@Document(indexName="populationstreamassignment")
public class Returned {
  @Id
  private String id;
  @Field(type= FieldType.text)
  private String memberId
  // getter and setter
}
```

Comment: That custom repository implementation is a life saver. Thanks.

Comment: @SandeepKhantwal Can you help with some working example of custom repo

Comment: @Shruti - answer posted in this thread with code example

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/1378) GitHub issue, you can not directly filter source using annotation and you need to use `NativeSearchQueryBuilder` for same.

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39461862/5489276) SO answer written by Val for NativeSearch query builder.

Answer (score 0):

@Shruti - pls note the CustomRepoImpl will be automatically searched by spring given the package is in the search path of spring boot. The name of the Impl should be (interface-name)Impl

```
@Repository
public interface NormalRepo extends ElasticsearchRepository<User, String>, CustomRepo {

  Optional<Instant> findByName(String name);
}

public interface CustomRepo {
  Optional<Instant> findByName(String name);
}

public class CustomRepoImpl implements CustomRepo {
  Optional<Instant> findByName(String name) {
    // your implementation
  }
}
```